# How to convert a vector into a matrix in Mata?

Tags: slice, stata

R's equivalent of what I want to do is like below:

```
> tmpv <- seq(1, 12, 1)
> tmpm <- matrix(tmpv, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

> tmpv
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
> tmpm
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
```

That is, I want to slice the vector to vectors with three elements and do the `rbind` work.

How can I do this in Stata Mata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
. mata : colshape(1..12, 3)
        1    2    3
    +----------------+
  1 |   1    2    3  |
  2 |   4    5    6  |
  3 |   7    8    9  |
  4 |  10   11   12  |
    +----------------+
```